# Constant spacing between QML items when one item is rotating

Tags: qt, qml

I have two elements that are supposed to be laid out in a column, but one of them is supposed to rotate as it is meant to visually depict the orientation changes read by an IMU. Since that rotating element is a rectangle, when it rotates it overlaps with the item below.

I have tried using both `Column` and `ColumnLayout` elements to see if the spacing between these elements can be kept constant even if the top element takes more space because of rotation, but no luck. I then removed both items from `Column` and tried binding the `y` property of the lower element to be `h*cos(rotation) + w*sin(rotation)` where `h` is height, `w` is width, and `rotation` is the angle of rotation in degrees of the top-most element. This results in the second item moving up and down pretty wildly on the screen instead of smoothly following the rotation of the first element.

What can I do to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Can you depict how you want it to look like?

Comment: I don't know how to provide pictures so you'd probably need to imagine this: let's say there are 2 rectangles, both are the same size, and both are twice as long as wide. Also, they are placed one above the other in a way that their longer sides are touching. Now if the top one were to be rotated and it's center point couldn't move, it would overlap with the bottom rectangle. That's what I'm facing right now. What I want is a way to push the lower rectangle further down, so that there is no overlap. Hope that helps..

Comment: So, that would sorta look like a piston moving up and down?

Comment: Btw did you check radians/degrees usage? JavaScript (co)sinus are in radians, where QML rotation is in degrees, wrong usage could make for some pretty wild rotation ;-)

Comment: I didn't think of that, I'll try changing it to degrees manually.

Comment: So converting from degrees to radians for sin and cos functions fixed the erratic behavior. Thanks for the suggestion.